# Keep Elements on Same Horizontal 'Row'

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have the following div in a page, but the button is being rendered below the input, despite there being plenty of room for them both in the same 'row' as I want them.  How can I force this 'same row' issue?

```
<div id="pageHeader" style="text-align: right;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchInput" runat="server" CssClass="searchTerm">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Search" onclick="searchButton_Click" />
</div>
```

NEW:  This issue was due to the fact that I'm using telerik ajax here, and had included `searchInput` as an updated control in the ajax settings of my RadAjaxManager.  This control 'wraps' all of its updated controls in block displayed divs by default.  I just had to override this default as follows:

```
protected void ajaxManager_AjaxSettingCreating(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxSettingCreatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.UpdatePanel.RenderMode = UpdatePanelRenderMode.Inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, input elements render with display:inline, which makes them appear in line :) However, in your case it seems that something is breaking the default behavior, so you will need to explicitly specify that you want display:inline instead of display:block. So, to sum up:

You can use the following CSS to obtain the desired view:

```
#pageHeader input
{
   display:inline !important;
}
```

Comment: It was the telerik radAjaxManager 'breaking' the default behaviour.  See my additions to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the code. It worked great. Telerik Ajaxmanager was the problem.

```
protected void ajaxManager_AjaxSettingCreating(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxSettingCreatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.UpdatePanel.RenderMode = UpdatePanelRenderMode.Inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your existing div to be an asp:Panel that gets updated by the RadAjaxManager (rather than the individual control(s)):

```
<asp:Panel id="pageHeader" runat="server" CssClass="righty">
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchInput" runat="server" CssClass="searchTerm">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Search" onclick="searchButton_Click" />
```

This may result in an additional control being posted back - and so is slightly worse performance-wise - but I think it improves readability somewhat.